# Erro ao tentar instalar watson_developer_cloud

Tags: python, pip, ibm, watson

Estou a tentar instalar o watson_developer_cloud usando o `pip`. Passado algum tempo e depois de algumas dependências a serem instaladas recebo o seguinte erro:

> Command "c:\users\eu\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Eu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0vfs931s\Twisted\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Eu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e3oae4j3\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Eu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0vfs931s\Twisted\

Já instalei o visual studio 2017 para tentar solucionar o problema, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta executar esse comando

> pip install --upgrade "watson-developer-cloud>=2.6.0"

Caso não dê certo, verifica se existe não já está instalada com

> pip freeze